# Convert an image placeholder into an HTML <img> tag using preg_replace()

Tags: php, html, image, preg-replace, contentplaceholder

I want to replace square-braced image placeholders with valid HTML markup.

A sample placeholder might look like this:

```
[img:http://example.com/_data/025_img.jpg]
```

I want is to change the bit where it says `[img: ... ]` with `<img>` tag and get a result like this:

```
<img src='http://example.com/_data/025_img.jpg' border='0' />
```

Additional information about user uploaded images relevant to this task:

1. user uploads images to their profile
2. image names are stored in db.
3. they are listed next to a form which has a textarea
4. while typing the text, I would like to offer the user to include one OR MORE of their images by adding the following tag `[img: ... ]` where `...` is the link that would be copied upon clicking on the images which are listed from the user gallery.
5. I'm using Codeigniter and passing the textarea through the view and into the controller->model where it is sanitized by a helper for all sorts of things ... sql/quotes etc.. XSS is also enabled on CI;
6. then I would like to scan the text and see where the user has the `[img: ... ]` tag and exchange that into a `<img>` tag and render the post with images followed by text.

So the actual input from the user will be something along the lines of:

```
The brown fox jumped over foo bar [img:http://example.com/_data/025_img.jpg] and then went to bed [img:http://example.com/_data/0277_img.jpg] while thinking about [img:http://example.com/_data/1115_img.jpg]
```

That is the reason I asked for `preg_replace()`, rather than `preg_match()`. `preg_match()` doesn't make the text follow the images.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?  A custom markup language?  Something like BBCode?  Have you thought about using an existing markup language and accompanying library?

Comment: Basically the user has a gallery with images, and I would like to let them include these images where they type the text in a user friendly way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's get the easy thing out of the way first.

```
/\[img:([^\]]+)\]/
```

That is:

- a literal `[img:`
- a capture group containing

  - a character class composed of

    - things that are not a literal `]`
  - repeating at least once
- a literal `]`

Run this through `preg_match` and element 1 in the match array will very likely be an image URL that you can easily insert into an `img` tag.

But you shouldn't.  Not right away.

First, this is insecure as heck.  What's going to happen when I write this?

```
[img:javascript:alert(document.cookie);]
```

Uhoh.  That's not going to be good.

You're *probably* going to want to make sure that the thing that the user claims is a URL really is a URL.  You can try doing this by calling [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url).  It will give you back an array of URL components.  Make sure that the thing has a domain and a path, and is served over HTTP or HTTPS.

Okay, but what happens when the user enters *this*?

```
[img:http://www.example.com/foo.jpg" onmouseover="alert(document.cookie)"]
```

That's a valid...ish... URL that will be successfully deconstructed by `parse_url` and may well pass basic checks for well-formedness.  Filtering out spaces and quotes (single *and* double) will be a good starting point, but there are still more things to worry about.

The bottom line is that markup like this is a vector in [**XSS**, or **Cross-site scripting** vulnerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

You can *probably* mitigate some of the threat by passing the URL through [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).  That will at least nuke quotes and brackets, and it's hard to be nasty with those taken care of.  Just watch out for character set sillyness, some non-UTF-8 character encoding can include things that are ASCII quotes...

You *probably* want to use a real markup language for this (even if it's just markdown), and you *probably* want to use a whitelist-based HTML filter like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org) on the result.  This will help protect you from some levels of insanity.

Remember, you're only paranoid if they *aren't* out to get you.  The web is full of people that are so stupid that they're malicious, and people that are so malicious that it's stupid.

Comment: I'm using CI to sanitize the input from the user, so basically when they submit the text field it goes through a security helper and then I was thinking of trying to achieve my goal of getting part of the text where it has some clue ie [img: ... ] and turning that into an image tag. XSS is turned on in CI config too. Does that change the situation? Any suggestion on how to procede?

Comment: I don't know anything about CodeIgniter's sanitization or XSS filtering, but let's assume it's decent.  Try breaking it using some of those examples.  Do your darndest to break out of the tag and be silly.  For example, `[img:"><b>Boo!</b>]` might pass straight through, as there's no javascript involved.  That said, it also fails the URL test.  Passing the whole thing through `htmlspecialchars` may also be an adequate level of protection.  Lemme actually add that...

Comment: Good answer, nice that you took up the possibility of malicious users!

Comment: Now that I'm testing the input, it seems very durable to me. JavaScript/SQL/html everything seems to be taken care of. Only thing that's left is to figure out how to exchange all the imaginary tags with real `<img>` tags while keeping the images between the text paragraph.

Comment: @Charles good point, security the first concern I could be wrong but probably the better sample for cross site scripting would be `[img:http://www.example.com/foo.jpg" onmouseover="alert(document.cookie)]`, no closing quote for onmouseover, otherwise browser could just disgust code an not valid

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like regex, you don't have to use them. At least not for this purpose.

The following should do:

```
$in = "[img:http://example.com/_data/025_img.jpg]";

if (strpos($in, "[img:") === 0)
{
    $in = "<img src='" . substr($in, 5, -1) . "' border='0' />";
}

echo $in;
```

However, this would be the regex-way:

```
$in = "[img:http://example.com/_data/025_img.jpg]";

preg_match("~\[img\:(.*?)\]~", $in, $matches);

if ($matches)
{
    echo "<img src='" . $matches[1] . "' border='0' />";
}
```

**Short explanation:**

The pattern is: `"~\[img\:(.*?)\]~"`

I use `~` as delimiter for the pattern. Your starting `[` has to be escaped, as it is a regex-character. `img` can stay as it is, the `:` has to be escaped again. After that, Any character can follow: `.*` - The question mark is to turn the selection to "ungreedy", otherwise, it would match to the end. Put it in (braces) so it is marked as output for `$matches`. After that, close the `]` again - that's all.

**Update**: See Gumbos comment, the `:` does not need to be escaped.

Comment: The `:` does not have to be escaped.

Comment: This replaces only one occurrence of the pattern. The use case suggests this is not what OP's looking for.

Comment: @DavidMüller, nobody likes regs, but in this paticular case code would be much elegant and safe using them

Answer (score 1):

Regex are hard, but yet powerful. I am not guru, at all, so not presume it is the best solution.

```
$regEx = '/\[img:http:\/\/[\w]{3,10}\.(com|org|us){1}[\w\/]{5,15}\.(jpg|png|gif){1}\]/i';

$string = 'someting before [img:http://example.com/_data/025_img.png], something after [img:http://example.org/_data/025_img.jpg] and end of the line EOL';
$pstring = $string;
$matches[0] = array();
preg_match_all($regEx, $string, $matches);
```

matches array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [img:http://example.com/_data/025_img.png]
            [1] => [img:http://example.org/_data/025_img.jpg]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => com
            [1] => org
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => png
            [1] => jpg
        )

)
```

Okay what's going on here:

1. regular expression

`/` - start regexpression
`\[img:http:\/\/` - every string has to start with `[img:http://`
`[\w]{3,10}` - than I expect 3 to 10 only numbers, letters and underscores line, which is gona be domain name (though I am not sure domain has to contain underscores, so good point for optimization)
`\.` - dot
`(com|org|us){1}` - one of these guys
`[\w\/]{5,15}` - from five to fifteen line as a path, note I included / here in addition
`\.` - dot
`(jpg|png|gif){1}` - one of these guys
`\]` - end of pattern
`/i` -make it case insensitive

2. [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php) find all matches in given string, additional substring matches from the branches into the brackets as a second and third element of `$matches`, I do little guess why, so if anyone could help understand this, it would be appreciated.
3. Next using simple string manipulations I could make replacement of all entrees

Something like this: (note no `if` statement as I added empty $matches[0] at the beginning, live so much better without `ifs` :))

```
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    $img = str_replace(array('[img:',']'), array('<img src="', '" />'), $match);
    $pstring = str_replace($match, $img, $pstring);
}
```

You may play around with regular expression, make it simple or more complex just as you need.

`$pstring` output is

```
someting before <img src="http://example.com/_data/025_img.png" />, something after <img src="http://example.org/_data/025_img.jpg" /> and end of the line EOL
```

here is playground http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bbu-e24

Comment: +1 for gluing it all together before I got to it, but you still need to worry about XSS here.

Comment: @Charlies, that's truly always needed to be worry about, as you pointed more detailed, see complex regExp now, less headache later

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = '[img:http://example.com/_data/025_img.jpg]';
$image = '<img src="'.str_replace(array("[img:","]"),"",$str).'" border="0">';
echo $image;?>
```

Comment: This puts the text which is before/after the [img: ... ] into the `<img>` tag which is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question details, I gather that you are in very good control of the image path / filename.

If this matter is purely about validating a url with a rather strict format and replacing the placeholder with an img tag, then write a pattern that matches the whole square-braced tag and capture the inner substring which represents the url of the image.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/M0VbC))

```
echo preg_replace(
         '~\[img:\s*(https?://example\.com(?:/\w+)*\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))]~',
         '<img src="$1" border="0" />',
         $text
     );
```

If want to be more discerning about the image source string or your control over the user input isn't as strong as you'd like, you can use `preg_replace_callback()` to, say, verify that the url exists in your database/server.

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
         '~\[img:\s*([^\'" \]]+)]~',
         function($m) {
             // do validation techiques
             if ($notValid) {
                 return '[invalid img]';
             }
             return "<img src='{$m[1]}' border='0' />";
         },
         $text
     );
```